# Can't seem to register my Bundle Id or change it in apple

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I was wondering if anyone else came across this problem, i was trying to register identifier in apple developer but its not accepting my Bundle id saying its already taken so i go to firebase console to change it and i cant because there is no option to change it, how do you fix this?

I am getting this error and in Firebase I can't see an option to change it:

```
An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value
An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.****' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

Comment: com.example.appname can not be used to upload build on store, (change your app id something like this com.company.appname or com.appname.appname) integrate firebase with this new id and then try to upload build on respective store :)

Answer (score 0):

The bundle ID is a unique identifier for the app, so no two apps can have the same bundle ID, if it's already taken, you can try with some new ones. For firebase, you cannot edit bundle id but you can remove the existing one and add a new one.

Comment: how do you remove the buddied from firebase console I don't see a remove button

Comment: Go to your Project Settings -> General Tab. Under "Your Apps" select the app at the bottom of the app information you will find the "Remove this app" button.